# Issues with Wordpress permalink /index.php/%postname% instead of %postname%

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I've tried to change my permalinks from example.com/index.php/postname to example.com/postname, but nothing has worked. When I change them in Wordpress, I get 404 errors for example.com/postname. I've noticed this is a common issue, but none of the suggested solutions have worked.

Mod_rewrite is enabled on the Apache server. The .htaccess file has been updated. Still nothing. In the meantime, I'm wondering if I could do a redirect that would send anyone with the example.com/postname link to example.com/index.php/postname. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to save permalink structure twice. If that doesnt work install wp 2017 theme >  delete your theme > reinstall your theme from scratch.

If you have cloned your website - you should go to the original site, back it up and then deploy it! a good plugin to  do this is updrafts if you don't know how to do it mannually. Don't use a cloning plugin - some plugins/themes don't work with them.